# mix deps error when 2 libraries share the same dependancy and require different versions

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am having issues resolving my phoenix app's dependencies:

My mix.exs file has:

```
{:phoenix, "~> 1.4.0"},
{:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.1"},
{:phoenix_ecto, "~> 4.0"},
{:ecto_sql, "~> 3.0"},
{:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
{:phoenix_html, "~> 2.11"},
{:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2", only: :dev},
{:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
{:jason, "~> 1.0"},
{:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"},
{:redix, ">= 0.0.0"},
{:extwitter, "~> 0.9.3"},      
{:timex, "~> 3.0"},
{:corsica, "~> 1.0"},
{:cachex, "~> 3.1"},
{:bamboo, "~> 1.1"},
{:bamboo_ses, "~> 0.1.0"},
{:comeonin, "~> 4.1"},
{:bcrypt_elixir, "~> 1.1"},
{:ex_machina, "~> 2.2", only: :test}

I then added this stripe library:

 {:stripity_stripe, "~> 2.0.0"},
```

Now when I perform a deps.get I see this error:

> Failed to use "hackney" (versions 1.13.0 to 1.15.1) because   bamboo
>   (versions 1.1.0 and 1.2.0) requires >= 1.13.0   stripity_stripe
>   (versions 2.0.0 and 2.0.1) requires ~> 1.12.1
>
> ** (Mix) Hex dependency resolution failed, change the version requirements of your dependencies or unlock them (by using mix
>   deps.update or mix deps.unlock). If you are unable to resolve the
>   conflicts you can try overriding with {:dependency, "~> 1.0",
>   override: true}

I already did this:

```
mix clean
rm mix.lock
mix deps.get
```

How do I use that override options?  How will this work if 2 libraries need different versions of a shared dependency?

Answer (score 6):

I found a [similar question on the elixir forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-do-hex-and-elixir-handle-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dependency/6979). Relevant quotes:

> You can’t have multiple versions of the same application running at the same time

and

> A single module can only exist in one version on the VM. So this gives restrictions on the application structure. This basically means everybody needs to agree on a single version.

Also, [the docs for `:override`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Deps.html) state:

> if set to `true` the dependency will override any other definitions of itself by other dependencies

This doesn't sound like what you want, because you will just be forcing stripity_stripe 2.0.0 to use a different version to what it expects.

It looks like you need to find a version of `stripity_stripe` that depends on versions of `hackney` that are also supported by `:bamboo, "~> 1.1"`.

- [bamboo 1.1](https://hex.pm/packages/bamboo/1.1.0) requires hackney ~> 1.13.0
- [stripity_stripe 2.2.2](https://hex.pm/packages/stripity_stripe/2.2.2) requires hackney ~> 1.13

So,

```
{:bamboo, "~> 1.1"},
{:stripity_stripe, "~> 2.2.2"}
```

looks good. I tested this with `mix deps.get` and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario if possible you can use

```
{:stripity_stripe, "~> 2.2.2"}
```

Or you should be able to add hackney as a dependency and apply `override: true`.

```
{:hackney, "~> 1.13", override: true}
```

Hope that helps